# Q: Moving between Excel Tabs with Indexes

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to loop through a series of Excel Tabs (Labelled Wk 1 to Wk 52) and extract the balance Value stored in Week 1 (K40) and have this value transferred to Week 2 (D10). (Week 3 would then be compared against Week 2 etc.) Please refer to the attached image. Do excel tabs have indexes you can refer towards? The reason for this is my pseudo-code below:

```
  For ws in Worksheets  'Cycle through all worksheets
      IF RIGHT(ws.name, 2) < RIGHT(ws.name + 1,2) THEN 
'As the worksheets are labelled Wk 1 Wk 2 etc. RIGHT 2 will only take the number values, not Wk
         Select ws.name
         tmpVar = Range("K40")
         Select ws.name + 1
         D10.Value = tmpVar
      END IF
  Next ws
```

If anyone could let me know if excel has tab indexes I can refer to that would be great. I looked through the Microsoft website (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221564(v=office.11).aspx) but what I need is to be able to move to the next tab (ws.name + 1) as that's what I don't know how to get. Apologies for the novice question - I'm still familiarizing myself with VBA.

[image: Balance Sheet Sample]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can refer to a worksheet by its index number.

```
dim w as long
for w = 1 to worksheets.count - 1
    with worksheets(w)
        If IsNumeric(Right(.Name, 2)) And IsNumeric(Right(Worksheets(w + 1).Name, 2)) Then
            if CLng(right(.name, 2)) = CLng(right(worksheets(w + 1).name, 2)) - 1 then
                worksheets(w + 1).cells(10, 4) = .cells(40, 11).value2
            end if
        end if
    end with
next w
```

Comment: Would the worksheets.count - 1 also take into account the two sheets that I have hidden? They are hidden because they are just used as named ranges and a default template.

Comment: Strange - I tried using the code and it mentioned a type mismatch. Any idea why?

Comment: The hidden worksheets should not be a problem but mathematical operations cannot be performed on non-numeric values. I've added some code to make sure that the right two characters of the worksheet names can be converted to numerical entities. A full list of the worksheet names (noting the one that you do not want to process) would be helpful.

Comment: Ah right - I assumed that since I use the Right() function it would convert the numbers from a txt string to a numerical format - that's why you typecasted it to Long correct? As for the worksheet names they are: Wk 1, Wk 2 .....Wk 52 and then the 2 hidden worksheets List and Blank.

Comment: Great - it seems to be working well Jeeped! Could I ask you to please explain the VBA code - I'd like to be able to break-it down so I can do this in the future myself. The only lines I'm unsure about are these two: 
if CLng(right(.name, 2)) = CLng(right(worksheets(w + 1).name, 2)) - 1 then
                worksheets(w + 1).cells(10, 4) = .cells(40, 11).value2
Why do we have to have the -1? Also, what is .value2?

Comment: So **List** and **Blank** should be at the end of the queue or at the beginning; not somewhere in the middle where they will foul up the 1, 2, 3, ... 52 sequence. The check for **IsNumeric** should take care of the rest.

Comment: Click these for [Range.Value property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195193.aspx) vs [Range.Value2 property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193553.aspx). Click [Range.Cells property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196273.aspx). If worksheets(3) is named **Wk 1** then you want worksheets(4) to be named **Wk 2** before you transfer the value across.

Answer (score 0):

The `Worksheets` collection does have an index property, and you can refer to worksheets by this index (as Jeeped illustrates)

However, the index of a sheet is its current position as displayed in Excel (count the tabs from the left, including counting hidden sheets).  This position can be changed by the user, so is risky to use in this case.

Better to make your `ws.name + 1` actually work

eg

```
Dim ThisWeekNum as long
Dim wsThisWeek as Worksheet
Dim wsNextWeek as Worksheet

ThisWeekNum = 1
Set wsThisWeek = Worksheets("Wk " & ThisWeekNum)
Set wsNextWeek = Worksheets("Wk " &  Val(Right$(wsThisWeek.Name, 2)) + 1)
```

Note, the user can also rename worksheets, so this has its risks too

Comment: Thanks for this Chris - I'll give it a shot and let you know how I go!

Comment: @azurekirby I think you have made a bad choice to method to use (based on your accept) - that code depends on the user not reordering the sheets _and_ not renaming sheets, _and_ not having hidden sheets in the sequence.

Comment: Hi Chris - Thanks for those points. I thought about it and this expenditure form will not be edited at all - once I have the 52 sheets created (which I do), no other sheets will be added to it. I've included this in a note. However, I also think your approach is great and I'll be considering that option for future changes.